# How to make interface between cordova app java script and android native

Tags: java, android, cordova

Hello everyone im facing a problem in cordova application i need to call the android native method with cordova java script method how it's possible?

what i done.

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity{

    JavaScriptInterface JSInterface;

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION = 1;
    @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        JSInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);

        loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        WebView webView = (WebView)appView.getEngine().getView();
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(JSInterface, "JSInterface");

    }

   public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;
        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }
        public void changeActivity(){startActivity(new Intent(mContext,ChildWebView.class));}
    }
}
```

i want to trigger changeActivity() method from java script code like :

```
<div class="Image" onclick="JSInterface.changeActivity();">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you:
https://github.com/square/duktape-android

The Duktape embeddable JavaScript engine packaged for Android.